# statistical range of a measurement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, statistical-inference

[image]

DoI need to find out the range? How to solve this problem? hints or canonical answer will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You know that $X_{max}-X_{min}=17$, where $X$ then denotes the length. Consider the extreme case when the given measurement is the maximum, i.e. $X_{max}=49.5$. What does this tell us about the minimum possible value of a measurement?

Comment: Why would we guess that 49.5 is the $X_{max}$?

Comment: @mathphy We wouldn't. It's an extreme case. Since the range is 17, the minimum *possible* value is 49.5-17, which would happen if it's the max. If it isn't the max, the max is higher than 49.5 and hence the minimum *possible* value is greater than 49.5-17. Do you see?

Comment: Got it. Therefore 33 and 34 are not allowed. right?

Comment: @mathphy Well, the opposite, 33 and 34 are allowed since they fall within the possible range. Hence they are possible measurements, whereas 31 and 32 are not possible.